# java inheritance setting value in parent class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an identical method that is repeated in every subclass and I'd like to refactor it to just one method in a superclass.

```
  public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
       private BoltHexHead bolt;
       private void computeFoo() {
          //Foo formula is identical in all subclasses. Need to move up
          setFoo(bolt.getDiameter() + bolt.getPitch() + bolt.getTpi());
       }
       private void computeBar() {
          //computeBar method in all subclasses but Bar formula is different amongst all subclasses
          setBar(bolt.getDiameter() - 2*bolt.getPitch() - 3*bolt.getTpi());
       }
       private void computeSeparation() {
          //computeSeparation method only exists for a Subclass 1
          setSeparation(bolt.getLength() - 2*nut.getFlatDia());
       }



  public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
       private BoltFlatHead bolt;
       private void computeFoo() {
          //Foo formula is identical in all subclasses. Need to move up
          setFoo(bolt.getDiameter() + bolt.getPitch() + bolt.getTpi());
       }
       private void computeBar() {
          //computeBar method here is different than in Subclass1
          setBar(bolt.getDiameter() - 4*bolt.getPitch() - 1/3*bolt.getTpi());
       }
       private void computeProtrusion() {
          //computeProtrusionmethod only exists for a Subclass 2
          setProtrusionmethod(bolt.getThreadAngle() - 6*bolt.getTpi());
       }
```

Initially I posted that `bolt` wasn't getting set in the SuperClass but was in the SubClass.  What I got working after my initial post was the following

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    protected Bolt<?> bolt;  <-- this was added but uses wildcard
    ...bolt getters/setter

       protected void computeFoo() {
          //Foo formula pulled up from all subclasses
          setFoo(bolt.getDiameter() + bolt.getPitch() + bolt.getTpi());
       }
  }

public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
  //private BoltHexHead bolt;   <-- commented this out in each subclass
}
```

This is a JSF app and in each controller bean I instantiate the specific joint attribute subclass and then set the specific bolt. It was an earlier design decision to use setters for setting the bolt (and other properties) in the subclass rather than doing it with the Constructor; but one refactor at a time.

```
Controller for a Bolt Analysis using a HexHead Bolt
    private SubClass1 sc1 = new SubClass1();
    private BoltHexHead bolt;
    sc1.setBolt(bolt);
    sc1.computeResults();

Controller for a Bolt Analysis using a FlatHead Bolt
    private SubClass2 sc2 = new SubClass2();
    private BoltFlatHead bolt;
    sc2.setBolt(bolt);
    sc1.computeResults();
```

So my question is, is it OK to use wildcard `Bolt<?> bolt` or is there a better approach?

Comment: what gives?  I'm not learning anything from the down votes.  Is it because I'm not asking the question according to the SO requirements or is it because my Java approach is way off.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Where does the value of the subclass `bolt` come from? Why not use a constructor?

Comment: @Pillar often I get bashed for putting too much code.  I'm trying to have a superclass with a method that computes a value using a formula that is applicable to all subclasses.

Comment: while i really don't get the code you posted (why is B in ChildA class definition  'Bolt<BoltSpec>' but the field bolt is of anopther type 'BoltHexHead' for example?): Why don't you just use a getter for bolt? define 'private B getBolt()' in the abstract superclass and have subclasses override that method.

Comment: @911DidBush, sorry I had a getter at one point,  I have been trying a number of different approaches.  let me update my question but I'm just trying to put a identical/duplicate method from all my subclasses into the parent but one of the variables (bolt) isn't getting set

Comment: make that "protected B getBolt()" in my previous comment. private methods cannot be overriden. of course

Answer (score 2):

> I'm just trying to put a identical/duplicate method from all my subclasses into the parent but one of the variables (bolt) isn't getting set

Thats because in java you cannot override fields. 
So your variables "private B bolt;" in your superclass and "private BoltHexHead bolt;" in your subclass are two different things. They actually both exist at the same time.

What you are trying to do actually isn't that complicated. You just need to clean up your code:

1. Only define "private B bolt;" and its setters/getters once in your superclass.
2. Only use those getters/setters to access bolt
3. If you want your subclass to have a "bolt" of the type "BoltHexHead" then define the generic parameter as such in the class definition `("extends JointAttribute<BoltHexHead>" instead of "extends JointAttribute<Bolt<BoltSpec>>")`

A simple example for demonstration purspose:

Superclass:

```
public class Superclass<T> {

    private T value;

    protected T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    protected void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    protected void print() {
        if(getValue()==null) {
            System.out.println("NULL");
        } else {
            System.out.println(getValue().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Subclass1:

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass<String> {

    public Subclass() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass subclass= new Subclass();
        subclass.print();
        subclass.setValue("test");
        subclass.print();
    }
}
```

Subclass2:

```
public class Subclass2 extends Superclass<Integer> {


    public Subclass2() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass2 subclass= new Subclass2();
        subclass.print();
        subclass.setValue(3);
        subclass.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok this has been helpful, but in the parent class, Eclipse says "The method getMinor_diameter_min() is undefined for the type B" and its fix is to cast to Bolt. But then "((Bolt) bolt).getMinor_diameter_min()" Eclipse complains that "Bolt is a raw type. References to generic type Bolt<S> should be parameterized" This message goes away when I change my Superclass back to JointAttribute<B extends Bolt<BoltSpec>>